# Angular2 host binding issue in AoT compilation

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, aot, angular2-hostbinding

Using the latest [Angular2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) (v5.4.1. / Angular 2.4.6) I'm trying to build my code with the AoT compiler. In a custom form input component I have this `host binding`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: 'mycustominput.component.html',
  host: {'(input-blur)': 'onInputBlur($event:any)'},
  providers: [INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
```

The build run with`npm run build:aot:prod` fails with this message

```
[at-loader] Checking finished with 2 errors
Error in bail mode: [at-loader] compiled/src/app/views/mycustominput.component.ngfactory.ts:142:35 
TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

The respective line (142) in the `ngfactory` is this:

```
141  if ((eventName == 'input-blur')) {
142    const pd_sub_0:any = ((<any>this.context.onInputBlur($event)) !== false);
143    result = (pd_sub_0 && result);
144  }
```

Obviously it has something to do with the host binding. No issue with this code in the dev build being JIT-compiled. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, my bad. It is just the `event` parameter missing in the callback method in my component that AoT now complains about.

changed

```
public onInputBlur() {...}
```

to

```
public onInputBlur(event) {...}
```